# How to check if a SQL script is compatible with sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, syntax, sql-server-2000, sql-scripts

I wrote a lot of scripts for SQL Server 2005, but now I have to rewrite those original scripts to make them work on SQL Server 2000.

I don't remember all the differences between 2005 and 2000. For instance, `CTE` was announced only in 2005 - and I must rewrite these queries to work on SQL Server 2000.

I need a way to check the syntax, while not having SQL Server 2000 at hand. Setting the compatibility level to 80 does not solve the issue - I get no warning, no errors.

**Is there a tool to use for cheking the syntax of the scripts? Can it be done with SSMS 2008?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a connection to the SQL Server 2000 database where you would execute the commands.

Then you set the parse only in the connection and "execute" the command. It will not get exceuted, but, if there's any syntax problem, it will throw the corredponding errors.

It's important to do it in th e database where you'd exceute the commands, as they depend on the database objects (existing table names, for example).

Here you have the information about this SET option:

[SET PARSEONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259208%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Good option. But the problem is that SQL Server 2000 is not available. So having SQL Server 2008 R2, I need to check syntax without actual deploy.

Comment: You can install a SQL Server Express 2000 and use it for this prupose.

Comment: No such thing as SQL Server 2000 Express. Maybe you meant MSDE? http://www.bing.com/search?q=download+msde+2000 ... If you go this route, PLEASE make sure you apply Service Pack 4. The last thing you want is to open yourself up to the slammer worm.

Comment: Yes, you're completley right. I meant MSDE. I didn't remember the name (and architecture and installation) change at this moment. Besides there's now a new version available which includes fixes for slammer: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22661

Comment: I'm a total loser. I have Win7 x64.
MSDE is not compatible with this version of windows. :)

Comment: MSDE (and even SQL Server 2000) is not supported in Vista and later OSs. In fact, support ended in August 2008. However maybe you get it to run doing the same thing of the last post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/aff7facf-5b64-473f-b543-e06b3c5e7420/. I recommend you to make a recovery point before installing, as I remember un- or re-installing MSDE became very hard on some occassions. Perhaps your customer could upgrade to a newer version. Even one of the newest Express editions could work for him. It's the 3rd generation since then!